# in R: which statistical test does compareGroups use?

Tags: r, group-differences

I know that compareGroups (package `compareGroups`) can be told to test for normal-distribution (via method = 4) and based on this chooses an appropiate test on its own. How do I see which test was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from the package documentation found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compareGroups/compareGroups.pdf):

Depending whether the row-variable is considered as continuous normal-distributed (1), continuous
non-normal distributed (2) or categorical (3), the following descriptives and tests are performed:
1- mean, standard deviation and t-test or ANOVA
2- median, 1st and 3rd quartiles (by default), and Kruskall-Wallis test
3- or absolute and relative frequencies and chi-squared or exact Fisher test when the expected frequencies is less than 5 in some cell
Also, a row-variable can be of class ’Surv’. Then the probability of ’event’ at a fixed time (set up
with ’timemax’ argument) is computed and a logrank test is performed.

The default value is 1 and can be changed by setting the `method` in the function (again from the documentation).

Comment: thanks! I read this documentation, but was wondering if compareGroups gives an output that makes it easy to see at a glance which test was used. Since "1- mean, standard deviation and t-test or ANOVA" still isn't very clear, for example...

Comment: I see. ANOVA is a generalisation of a t-test beyond two groups (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance)). Therefore, it should only depend on the number of groups you supply the function!

Comment: Yes! I understand that  I can deduct which test was used, but I thought there might be an output to avoid stupid mistakes. For example "...and chi-squared or exact Fisher test when the expected frequencies is less than 5 in some cell...". In this case, I strictly speaking I have to perform a test which tests if the expected frequencies is less than 5 in some cell in order to know which test was used?

Comment: Right, but you would know a-priori how many groups you are supplying to the function right? Because given the selection of (1), (2) or (3) the test used is a deterministic function of the number of groups. So in the case you mention "1- mean, standard deviation and t-test or ANOVA" you will get a t-test if the number of groups is 2 and an ANOVA in case there are more than 2?

Comment: Yes, the number of groups supplied to the function is pretty clear to me=)
But regarding my second example when supplying categorical variables (3), strictly speaking I have to perform additional tests to know which test was used, correct?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean in that situation. Perhaps you can derive it from one of the descriptive statistics you obtain when evaluating object$var with object the result of the compareGroups call and $var the variable you are unsure about!